# R: plotting proportions in a grouped barplot

Tags: r, plot

```
a = c(3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 2)
b = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
barplot(t(table(a, b)), beside = TRUE)
```

[image]

```
> table(a, b)
   b
a   1 2
  1 1 0
  2 2 0
  3 1 0
  4 0 1
  5 1 0
  6 1 0
```

Instead of plotting the counts, I would like to plot the proportions instead. In the vector b, there are a total of 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 6 counts for b = 1. So for the very first bar (dark gray), I would like to plot 1/6 = 0.17 instead. For the second dark gray bar, it would be 2/6 = 0.33. And the light gray bar would be 1/1 = 1 in the 4th group. Essentially I would like to plot this table instead

```
   b
a      1 2
  1 0.17 0
  2 0.33 0
  3 0.17 0
  4 0    1
  5 0.17 0
  6 0.17 0
```

How can I subset the table to calculate the proportions and then barplot those proportions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters,

```
t(table(a,b))
```

is...

```
table(b,a)
```

To get what you want, employ:

```
barplot(prop.table(table(b,a),margin=1), beside=TRUE)
```

This will give the proportions for each row (`margin=1`). You could make this `2` if you wanted the column proportions instead.